# How can I use a client certificate stored on S3 in Cypress?

Tags: amazon-s3, cypress, client-certificates

How can I pass the S3 path to the "pfx", "passphrase" properties, according the Cypress's [clientCertificate configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/client-certificates)?

I am currently able to use a locally stored certificate using Cypress's clientCertificate configuration like so, but would like to be use the cert stored in S3 -

```
"clientCertificates": [
   {
       "url": "...",
       "ca": [],
       "certs": [
           {
               "pfx": "certs/cert.p12",
               "passphrase": "certs/cert-passphrase.txt"
           {
   }
]
```